# Template declaration inside if statement

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement

I'm trying to understand the C++ template. I'm not too much expert in programming so sorry if I'm saying or writing something stupid.
I have the following Template

```
template <class C> class A
{
   public:
   A(){};
   // some functions here
}
```

In my main function I want something as

```
int a;

// a function that evaluates if a must be set to 1 or 0

if(a==1)
{
  A  var<Class1>();
}else{
  A  var<Class2>();
}
```

I know that this is not possible to do, but I'm asking how can I achieve something like this.

Comment: Provide an abstract base class for `A`.

Comment: This isn't enough to know what you actually plan on doing with `var`. The code you have will work (losing the `()`); but is pointless unless you plan on using `var` exclusively where declared (within the block scope of either the `if` or the `else`). If your plan is to have `var` live beyond either/both of those scope, *then* this falls on its face and you need something different.